# NullReferenceException Accessing Connection String

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

```
UserStore<IdentityUser> userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
userStore.Context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString =
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["CandleDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

the issue I'm currently experiencing is that i keep getting a error in line 2, the error is:

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: `Context`, `Database` and/or `Connection` is null.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.